# Subtracting a date in one column from previous unique date in another column in R

Tags: r, datediff, data-preprocessing

I have a dataframe as following:

```
ID   DPREL          Dt_biop      
292  2012-06-11    2014-03-06    
292  2013-01-10    2014-03-06
292  2015-05-21    2014-03-06
292  2017-09-05    2014-03-06
292  2012-06-11    2015-05-21   
292  2012-09-07    2015-05-21
292  2012-09-07    2017-10-26
292  2013-01-10    2017-10-26
292  2015-05-21    2017-10-26
805  2013-09-09    2020-11-19
805  2020-03-01    2020-11-19
```

I need to add a new column "Diff" which is the difference between each DPREL and previous unique Biopsy date(Dt_biop), not exactly the previous row. In fact the new column should look like this:

```
ID   DPREL         Dt_biop       Diff
292  2012-06-11    2014-03-06    
292  2013-01-10    2014-03-06
292  2015-05-21    2014-03-06
292  2017-09-05    2014-03-06
292  2012-06-11    2015-05-21    -633
292  2012-09-07    2015-05-21    -545
292  2012-09-07    2017-10-26    -986
292  2013-01-10    2017-10-26    -861
292  2015-05-21    2017-10-26     0
805  2013-09-09    2020-11-19 
805  2020-03-01    2020-11-19
```

Note that the diff column should be created based on each ID. I already tried the following code.

```
DATA2 <- DATA2 %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 arrange(Dt_biop) %>%
 mutate(diff = DPREL - lag(Dt_biop, default = first(DPREL)))
```

Although it works, it calculates the difference between each DPREL and its previous Dt_biop row and this is not correct. It should calculate the difference between each DPPREL in each row with previous unique Dt_biop. For ID 292, we have 3 unique Dt_biop.

For the first biopsy in each ID, I do not need to calculate any diff becuase there is no previous biopsy. So, the diff value for these rows should be empty.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Posting data-as-image is a good way to loose friends very quickly: put yourself in our shoes: we have to manually transcribe your data before we can start to help you.  Why should *we* do that when *you* have a trivially easy way (`dput()`) to help us help you?

Comment: Hi @Limey. As suggested, I tried to add the dataframe,  but I am not sure if it is in the right format. Please let me know if it is ok and my question is visible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tidyverse option using `tidyr::fill`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(date = if_else(Dt_biop > lag(Dt_biop), lag(Dt_biop), NA_Date_)) %>%
  fill(date) %>%
  mutate(diff = DPREL-date) %>%
  select(-date)

# # A tibble: 11 x 4
# # Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID   DPREL      Dt_biop    diff     
#    <int> <date>     <date>     <drtn>   
# 1    292 2012-06-11 2014-03-06   NA days
# 2    292 2013-01-10 2014-03-06   NA days
# 3    292 2015-05-21 2014-03-06   NA days
# 4    292 2017-09-05 2014-03-06   NA days
# 5    292 2012-06-11 2015-05-21 -633 days
# 6    292 2012-09-07 2015-05-21 -545 days
# 7    292 2012-09-07 2017-10-26 -986 days
# 8    292 2013-01-10 2017-10-26 -861 days
# 9    292 2015-05-21 2017-10-26    0 days
# 10   805 2013-09-09 2020-11-19   NA days
# 11   805 2020-03-01 2020-11-19   NA days
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(292L, 292L, 292L, 292L, 292L, 292L, 292L, 
292L, 292L, 805L, 805L), DPREL = structure(c(15502, 15715, 16576, 
17414, 15502, 15590, 15590, 15715, 16576, 15957, 18322), class = "Date"), 
    Dt_biop = structure(c(16135, 16135, 16135, 16135, 16576, 
    16576, 17465, 17465, 17465, 18585, 18585), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```